# Source files of GCE instance from an image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have created a VM instance using a docker image stored in Google container registry. The instance is working fine and I'm happy. What I am trying to figure out is where the source files are stored.

When I access the VM via SSH and navigate to usr/src/app I don't see anything. In my dockerfile I specified that directory to be used as the app directory.

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
```

Where can I see the source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source files will be located in the location you specified ***within*** the container in question.

After you access the VM via SSH, you may run `docker ps` to get the list of containers running on your instance. You'll then be able to SSH into your running container via the following command:

```
docker exec -it <container name> /bin/bash
```

Once in there you should be able to see your source code in `/usr/src/app`.